# How do I get Visual Studio to properly place DLLs from Nuget Package in UWP apps?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, uwp, nuget

I have a C++ based UWP app that makes a reference to a DLL from a Nuget package.   The app builds fine, but when I try to run it, the launch fails with error 0xc0000135 ('A dependent dll was not found').

After a bunch of debugging, I found that the referenced DLL is in the Debug directory, but **not** in the Debug\AppX directory (where it needs to be).   If I manually copy the DLL to the AppX directory, the app launches, but I don't want to be doing this all the time.

How do I get Visual Studio to properly place this DLL?

Comment: You can copy any required files as a Post-Build step

Comment: @VTT that's kinda lame, but I'll consider it....

Comment: Well, that is how things always been. Note that there are no tools for tracking binary compatibility either so you need to manually check that DLL from nuget is actually compatible with your executable. Or (better) build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get Visual Studio to properly place DLLs from Nuget Package in UWP apps?

Just like VTT said, you can use post-build to copy DLL file to the Debug\AppX directory:

```
xcopy /Y <PathForDll>\Your.dll $(TargetDir)AppX\
```

Besides, since this dll comes from nuget package, you can add a copy task in the `.targets` file and set this `.targets` into the `\build` folder in the nuget package, so that you do not need to add the post-build event after install the nuget package(which make you feel a little lame).

To accomplish this, add .targets file in the `\build` folder in the `.nuspec` file:

```
<files>  
    <file src="ProjectName.targets" target="build/ProjectName.targets" />  
</files>
```

Add following code in the `.targets` file：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToCopy Include="<PathForDll>\Your.dll"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)AppX\"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Hope this helps.